# how to alert using bootstrapon click div ( add class )

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, click

I am using something on click() function. I want to use bootstrap alert class to look alert box good. How to use it. I mean where I need to use bootstrap alert class.

```
<script>
 function goodWork(){
         alert("GOOD WORK!");
        }

</script>

<body>
  <div class="num" "alert alert-success" id="correct" onclick="goodWork()">
        3
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should put the class next to `<div class="num`

Comment: You can't customize the native `alert()`. If you want to use the Bootstrap alert, then you should add it as HTML to your page.

Comment: yes its Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a possible solution to your problem. What you wanted to do was calling a function that displays a bootstrap alert. However, the problem was that the `alert()` function only displays the default, built in, alert.

In order to display a bootstrap alert, just as simple as a normal alert I have added some javascript and some html.

First I have put the custom alert in a html `<template>` element. This element is not rendered by the browser. Then I have create the function `customAlert(text)`. You can pass any text to this function and it will display it in the predefined format. This function also clones the custom alert from the `<template>` tag and appends it to the `<body>`.

```js
function goodWork() {
  customAlert("GOOD WORK!");
  //console.log("yes?");
}

function customAlert(text) {
  //Get the alert from the template element
  var alertBox = document.getElementById("alert").content;
  //clone the alert
  var cln = alertBox.cloneNode(true);
  //set the message of the alert
  cln.querySelectorAll("strong")[0].innerText = text;
  //display the alert in the body
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(cln);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <p>Click on the button to display an alert:</p>
  <button onclick="goodWork();">click me</button>

  <template id="alert">  
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in num">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <strong>Goodwork</strong>
  </div>
 </template>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps! If not, please comment.